# Handling onClick for a particular element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a card grid where the user can expand the card to view its details. The issue I am facing with the react hooks is that the function is getting called for all cards instead of the particular card I am clicking the button. As a result, all the cards are getting expanded.
Here's my code for reference.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function Album(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
      <Card.Text >
        <p className={classes.heading}>
          {props.blogTitle}
        </p>
      </Card.Text>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Img 
          src={props.imgsrc} 
          alt="Card image"
          className={classes.cardMedia} 
        />
      {props.cardOpen && 
        <AnimatePresence>
        <motion.div
        initial={{opacity:0}}
        animate={{opacity:1, transition:0.3}}
        >
        <p className={classes.desc} gutterbottom>
          {props.blogDescription}
        </p>
        <div href={props.blogLink}
          style={{color:"gray", fontSize:17, fontFamily:"calibri", fontSmooth: "auto", cursor:"pointer", display:"flex", justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <LocalLibraryIcon style={{marginRight:7}}/>Read blog
        </div>
        </motion.div>
      </AnimatePresence> 
    }
     
    {(props.cardOpen) ?
      <div onClick={props.isOpen} style={{float:"right", cursor:"pointer"}}>
        <ExpandLessIcon style={{fontSize:40, marginTop:10, color:"  #909090"}}/>
    </div> : (
      <div onClick={props.isOpen} style={{float:"right", cursor:"pointer"}}>
        <ExpandMoreIcon style={{fontSize:40, marginTop:10, color:"  #909090"}}/>
    </div>
    )}
    </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function ProjectItems() {
  const [cardOpen, setCardOpen]= useState(false);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <main>
        <div className={classes.heroContent}>
          <Container maxWidth="md">
            <Typography
              variant="h2"
              align="center"
              color="textPrimary"
              className={classes.root}
              gutterBottom
            >
              Blogs
            </Typography>
          </Container>
        </div>
        <Container maxWidth="md">
        <Grid container spacing={4}>
        {blogData.map(post => (
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}  key={post.id}>
                <div>
              <Album
                  blogId={post.id}
                  blogTitle={post.title}
                  blogDescription={post.summary}
                  imgsrc={post.image_link}
                  blogLink={post.article_link}
                  isOpen={()=>{
                    setCardOpen(!cardOpen);
                  }}
                  cardOpen={cardOpen}
                />
          </div>
          </Grid>
          ))}    
          </Grid>      
        </Container>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: try ` isOpen={()=>{setCardOpen(post.id);}} cardOpen={cardOpen===post.id}`

Comment: What is `blogData`? it is not there in props

Comment: Here you store only one single variable in state for all cards, you should have separate switch for each card instead. Try to declare a set of opened card ids in state. When particular card is clicked - add or remove it from that set. Then, as @NadiaChibrikova said, render card in your map function as opened if its id is presented in that set.

Comment: That works but what to do for shrinking the card back to normal? @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: `setCardOpen(null)` should do the trick : `setCardOpen(id => {if(post.id==id) return null; return post.id;})`

Comment: @DmitriyBotov looks a bit challenging but will try. Thanks!

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Okay got it! Thanks for the help!